# Values in array being duplicated causing several rows being inserted into database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreach, insert

I am using `foreach loops` to select several values that I want to insert into my database. By doing this, I get duplicated rows into the database if the chosen material is the same for several products. I tried using `array_unique()` after fetching all on `$aOrders`, but it still seems to duplicate the data. This is my code:

```
try {
    foreach($_POST["txtName"] as $name){
      foreach($_POST["txtMaterial"] as $material){

        $sQuery = $db->prepare('SELECT id FROM products WHERE name = :sName AND material = :sMaterial AND size = :sSize');
        $sQuery->bindValue(':sName', $name);
        $sQuery->bindValue(':sMaterial', $material);
        $sQuery->bindValue(':sSize', $_POST["txtSize"]);
        $sQuery->execute();
        $aOrders = $sQuery->fetchAll();

        foreach($aOrders as $aOrder){

          $sQuery2 = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO orders VALUES (null, :sUser, :sProduct, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)');
          $sQuery2->bindValue(':sUser', 2);
          $sQuery2->bindValue(':sProduct', $aOrder['id']);
          $sQuery2->execute();

          if($sQuery2->rowCount()){
            echo '{"status":1, "message":"success"}';
          }else{
            echo '{"status":0, "message":"error"}';
          }
        }
      }
    }   
}catch( PDOException $e ){
  echo '{"status":0, "message":"exception"}';
}
```

I don't know how else to only get the values once. Does anybody have an idea to what I can do? Thanks.

Comment: is it because you have a loop within a loop?

Comment: Firstly - you need to just use 1 loop and fetch the index to access the other arrays - `foreach($_POST["txtName"] as $index => $name){` and then use `$_POST["txtMaterial"][$index]`.

Comment: Secondly - look into `INSERT... SELECT...` to do this more compactly.

Comment: I am not sure of syntax but don't do fetch all, rather `$sQuery->fetch()` and then `$sQuery->next()`. please check on the syntax.